# MySQL's LPAD String Function in JPA Query?

Tags: jpql

May I know how to convert the following MySQL SQL to JPA query?

```
SELECT * FROM ORDER
WHERE LPAD(BATCH, 2, ' ') < LPAD('X', 2, ' ') ;
```

What I couldn't figure out is the LPAD() string function in JPA.

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I know that is a very old post, but i am always be questioned by some colleagues  when they are building JPA queries how to do the same thing.
Almost never you will find a perfect fit function to do what do you want. But, using some logic you can get the same result, in full JPA.

A example of LPAD.

```
Expression<String> numberWithZeroLeft = builder.concat("0000", root.get("myNumber")); //Return something like 000012
Expression<Integer> expressionLength = builder.length(numberWithZeroLeft);
Expression<String> numberLpad = builder.substring(numberWithZeroLeft, e.builder.sum(expressionLength, -3), e.builder.literal(4)); //Return something like 0012

query.select(numberLpad);
```

Think in something like:

```
I have a string X, and need a string formatted in 4 zeros.
So we will get 0000 + X => "0000X"
And now just get the 4 last characters using substring.
```

I hope that help someone.

Cheers. =]

Answer (score 0):

In EclipseLink 2.1 there is a function FUNC for calling database specific functions, for example:

```
FUNC('LPAD', BATCH, 2, ' ') < FUNC('LPAD', 'X', 2, ' ')
```

From EclipseLink 2.4 and JPA 2.1 there is FUNCTION operator with the same functionality