# In JPA using Postgresql lpad function but it is failing to execute

Tags: java, database, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

In JPA I am doing the following. Although lpad function executes correctly I have checked in pgadmin v4. I have `postgres 9.5.14`. Apparently the code below seems fine

```
Expression<String> eTaskID = root.get("taskID").as(String.class);
Expression<Integer> length = cb.literal(4);
Expression<String> fillText = cb.literal("0");
Expression<String> ePaddedTaskID = cb.function("LPAD", String.class, eTaskID, length, fillText);
```

It fails and gives following error

```
05-14-20 00:33:10.257 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] WARN  o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42883
05-14-20 00:33:10.257 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - ERROR: function lpad(text) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 1722
05-14-20 00:33:10.258 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Failed to complete request: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
05-14-20 00:33:10.260 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet] with root cause
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: function lpad(text) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 1722
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2533) ~[postgresql-42.2.12.jar:42.2.12]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2268) ~[postgresql-42.2.12.jar:42.2.12]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:313) ~[postgresql-42.2.12.jar:42.2.12]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:448) ~[postgresql-42.2.12.jar:42.2.12]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:369) ~[postgresql-42.2.12.jar:42.2.12]
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I have found the following Question/Answer.
2. It has worked and given the desired result.
3. But still if someone can actually **answer** the solution to the **above exception**, it will be great.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/56858713/578855

Reproducing the code snippet from the above post here

```
Expression<String> numberWithZeroLeft = builder.concat("0000", root.get("myNumber")); //Return something like 000012
Expression<Integer> expressionLength = builder.length(numberWithZeroLeft);
Expression<String> numberLpad = builder.substring(numberWithZeroLeft, builder.sum(expressionLength, -3), builder.literal(4)); //Return something like 0012
```